# Trigger for progress bar 100%

Tags: swift, uikit

I build a small App for myself to save and display some data in a GUI on my iPhone.

To see the sync status of the data I've got a progress bar:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    ...
    @IBOutlet weak var syncHealthProgress: UIProgressView!
    ...
}
```

The data is synced with url requests encapsulated in a separate class from which the progress bar (call-by-reference parameter) is updated:

```
 class ApiService {
     ...
     // function to sync some data, called multiple times from UIViewController
     class func syncQlData(progressBar: UIProgressView) -> Void {
         ...
         let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
             data, response, error in

             // update progress bar
             DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                 // increment progress bar
                 progressBar.progress += (1 / Float(ViewController.progressBarSteps))
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Problem: The API calls are asynchronous. But when the sync is finished I what to do some task like updating the data in GUI and save the synced data to local storage.

I tried to use Key-Value-Observing on the `syncHealthProgress` but it doesn't take effekt on the `.progress` property.

Is there any way to trigger an action from within the `UIViewController` when the progress bar is on 100%?

Comment: Maybe you should have a method like updateProgress(to : CGFLoat), and in it, do something special for 100% case

Comment: I plan to use some other service classes so that I have to implement this in multiple classes. Another problem is to call a method in UIViewController instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use delegate for that.

In ApiService above class implement

```
protocol ApiServiceDelegate: class {
   func updateProgressBar()
}
```

and add a property inside class

```
weak var apiServiceDelegate: ApiServiceDelegate!
```

in your syncQLData call the updateProgressBar() like

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
         data, response, error in

         // update progress bar
         self. apiServiceDelegate.updateProgressBar()

}
```

In your ViewController (where the progress bar is) add the protocol like

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, ApiServiceDelegate
```

Where you instantiating your ApiService you have to set the delegate.

I think you do something like

```
let apiService = ApiService()
apiService.syncQlData(syncHealthProgress)
```

you have to change that to

```
let apiService = ApiService()
apiService.apiServiceDelegate = self
apiService.syncQlData(syncHealthProgress)
```

Now you can implement the function of the delegate in ViewController like

```
func updateProgressBar() {
   syncHealthProgress.progress += (1 / Float(progressBarSteps))
}
```

Comment: @SvenReuter Kein Problem :)